# Engines field is required but was not found in functions\package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this error. Please help me.

> Engines field is required but was not found in functions\package.json.
>   To fix this, add the following lines to your package.json:
>    "engines": {
>           "node": "8"
>         }

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Need update firebase cli;

> npm install -g firebase-tools

Reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#macos

Answer (score 4):

You should insert the node engines into your package.json. Try this:

```
{
    "name": "functions",
    "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
    "dependencies": { 
        "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0", 
        "firebase-functions": "^2.0.4", 
        "lodash": "^4.17.10" 
    }, 
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 8.0.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

For more information, checkout the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) if you're interested.

Edit: 
Some commenters mentioned that setting the node version sould be done without the decimals. So try:

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">= 8"
}
```

also.

Comment: hello i have this errori  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Service Usage API has not been used in project 563584335869 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/serviceusage.googleapis.com/overview?project=5636758433655869 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
PS C:\Users\samir\Desktop\nuovacartella\functions>

Comment: Try typing ```npm i``` into the console. Then run it again.

Comment: I have the same mistake

Comment: Error: HTTP Error: 403, Service Usage API has not been used in project 563584335869 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/serviceusage.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
PS C:\Users\samir\Desktop\nuovacartella\functions>

Comment: Have you visited the linked website & enabled the Service Usage API?

Comment: get an error when I open the browser

Upload failed.
An error occurred while loading /apis/api/serviceusage.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869. Try again.

Comment: Are you using the correct Google use account? Also, try clearing the cache in the browser.

Comment: Just curious, why `engines` field is required? The npm document doesn't mention anything about when it is required.

Comment: I'm not sure. He didn't provide much information on what he was doing. So I just assumed it had something to do with the package.

Comment: === Deploying to 'datingmuslimanetchat'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. The only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node": "10"}. Note that Node.js 6 is now deprecated.
PS C:\Users\samir\Desktop\folder>

Comment: Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. The only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node": "10"}. Note that Node.js 6 is now deprecated.

Comment: Did you try using `"node": "8"`? @SeverinKlug

Comment: Yes - The reason I commented this Error message, was to point out that the command expects node to be exactly ```{"node": "8"}``` and not as in your answer suggestet ```{"node": ">= 8.0.0"}```. Following the Error Message's integer 8 resolved my issue. You could validate this soultion and check if the ```{"node": ">= 8.0.0"}``` you suggested works or not and then maybe update your original answer if it realy only accepts ```{"node": "8"}```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update. I'll add that to my solution. @SeverinKlug

Answer (score 2):

**For devs, who have issues with Firebase Functions Deploy**

I have managed to fix the issue, with specifying the `runtime` node version in `firebase.json`. Like this:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build",
    "runtime": "nodejs10" // <- In here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

=== Deploying to 'datingmuslimanetchat'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. The only valid choices are: {"node": "8"} and {"node": "10"}. Note that Node.js 6 is now deprecated.
PS C:\Users\samir\Desktop\folder>